# SSL with eclipse

Tags: eclipse, ssl

I want to write client-server using SSL with eclipse. I generate key using this command:

`keytool -genkey -keystore mySrvKeystore -keyalg RSA`

Then I want to import key to jre keystore to use eclipse to start applications using SSL. I use this command:

```
C:\jdk1.6.0_21\bin>keytool -import -alias klucz -file C:\mySrvKeystore -keystore C:\jre6\lib\security\cacerts
```

Next I type passoword 'changeit' and I get error:

```
keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Input not an X.509 certificate
```

Do someone know how can I handle with that? Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for the steps to create a self-signed certificate. You can follow the procedure shown below or simply google "keytool self signed certs"

http://www.sslshopper.com/article-how-to-create-a-self-signed-certificate-using-java-keytool.html

Answer (score 1):

The error is self explanatory.

You are trying to import a keystore to a keystore.
This is not possible.
You can import only a certificate to a keystore.

So in your case you should first export the certificate from `mySrvKeystore` and then you can import it to cacerts.

But why don't you tell us what you are trying to do here?

For a client/server using SSL you don't need to import anything to `cacerts`

You can use your keystore.